# Probability that two samples from a multinomial distribution intersect in a specific way

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, multinomial-distribution, combinatorics

The following combinatorially difficult problem has obvious applications in information retrieval and bioinformatics but I haven't seen its solution discussed anywhere.

I am interested in computing the probability that two samples drawn from a multinomial distribution have a specific intersection of elements.

To make this concrete, imagine that I have a large urn containing balls of $m$ different colors and that the probability of drawing a ball with color $c$ is known to be $p(c)$, $c \in \{1\ldots m\}$. Next, imagine that I draw two samples from the urn with replacement, $S_1$ and $S_2$, whose sizes are $n_1 = |S_1|$ and $n_2 = |S_2|$.

Denote the number of balls in $S_1$ drawn with color $c$ as $f_1(c)$. And similarly, denote the number of balls in $S_2$ with color $c$ as $f_2(c)$. Now let $g(c)$ denote the number of balls with color $c$ that $S_1$ and $S_2$ have in common,
$$
g(c) = \min \{ f_1(c), f_2(c) \}.
$$

I am interested in computing the probability of observing a particular set of items common to both $S_1$ and $S_2$, call it
$\vec{g} = \langle g(1), g(2), \ldots, g(m) \rangle$, resulting from the described sampling process. That is, I want to compute
$$
P\bigl( \vec{g} ~ \bigl| ~ p(1), ..., p(m), |S_1|=n_1, |S_2|=n_2 \bigr).
$$

I am well aware that this probability can be estimated through monte sampling, but doing so is extremely inefficient when there are many different colors of balls (large $m$) and the sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ contain more than just a handful of items.

Are there other, more efficient approaches to estimating the intersection probability for two draws from a multinomial distribution? I am surprised I haven't found any given that this seems to be a fundamental problem in probability.

Comment: That this is *not* a fundamental problem is evident from the fact that any solution must depend on the specific (but *arbitrary*) distributions involved.  Consequently, describing the sampling distribution of subsets has exponential complexity in $m.$

Comment: Thanks. So I guess this is why I haven't seen any information retrieval methods formulate query<=>document similarity based on these probabilities... ?